# Drop unique key constraint from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I applied some of the answers read here and I think I screwed my DB up. I was trying to drop an unique constraint (asignatura_id) of my table Horarios:

```
CREATE TABLE Horarios (
horario_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
horario DATETIME,
asignatura_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (horario_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (asignatura_id) REFERENCES Asignaturas (asignatura_id)
);
```

I followed this steps:

1. SHOW INDEX FROM Horarios;

I checked that Horarios had this Key_names: (PRIMARY, horario_id, horario_id_2, asignatura_id). So I guessed that horario_id_2 was the index to remove prior to remove unique constraint)

2. DROP INDEX horario_id_2 ON horarios;
3. ALTER TABLE horarios ADD FOREIGN KEY (asignatura_id) REFERENCES asignaturas(asignatura_id);

This way I didn´t remove the unique constraint because I can see "asignatura_id" column from table horarios has this unique constraint yet...

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not clear - you had 3 indexes and you dropped the wrong one (horario_2)?

Comment: Yeah, that´s it. I have an unique constraint in asignaturas_id column and I need to remove it safely, but before I did this mistake and now I don´t know how to fix it.